# Can I store ElasticSearch index straight in file system?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Can we store *ElasticSearch* index on disk (no service installation), as we can do with *Lucene*?

Can we have it that simple as this?

```
...
File indexDir = new File(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35);
IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, analyzer);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, conf);
...
```

If yes, then how it could be implemented?